# Converting Tree to list

Tags: tree

So I have this prolog program that prints out the number of positive numbers in a tree.

```
positive(void).
positive(tree(L, Root, R), P) :- Root > 0, positive(L, X),positive(R, Y).
positive(tree(L, Root, R), P) :- positive(L,X), positive(R,Y).
```

Instead of outputting the number of positive numbers in this tree, I want to output the actual numbers in a list that are positive

Comment: Prefix, infix, postfix order? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can construct a predicate that transforms the positive elements to a list, but a more elegant approach, is to construct a predicate that unifies with all positive numbers in a tree. Like:

```
positive(tree(_,X,_),X) :-
    X > 0.
positive(tree(L,_,_),X) :-
    positive(L,X).
positive(tree(_,_,R),X) :-
    positive(R,X).
```

This is *prefix* notation where we unify with `X` as the first of the three clauses. In case you want *infix*, you can swap the first and second prediate. In case *postfix* is required, then we can swap the first and third clause.

Now we can use the `findall/3` meta-predicate:

```
positive_list(T,L) :-
    findall(P,positive(T,P),L).
```

The advantage of constructing such a `positive/2` predicate, is that we can also construct (partially grounded) trees that contain the positive number (with `positive(T,3).` for instance), further ground a partially grounded tree that should contain a positive number (like `T = tree(empty,3,_), positive(T,5).`), and furthermore query if a positive number is in the tree (with `positive(tree(void,3,void),2).`).